# Woocommerce blurry product image

Tags: html, wordpress, image, woocommerce, blurry

http://doubleknityarn.com.hk/

This is my web home page. Everything goes fine, except the 4 product images in the middle of the website are too blurry.

I have already done the "Regenerate Thumbnail" plugin, resize the image size in the setting of display under woocommerce products, but still I cannot obtain clearer photos.

Any one can help?  I have tried many methods already.

Comment: If you have this kind of problems: The best thing is to contact your theme shopkeeper author team and to open a support ticket or check in their support threads for similar problems. On chrome is ok now. You have to test in different platforms and browsers…

Answer (score 1):

If I display the url of one of this images, I got:

`…/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DSC09923.jpg?resize=116%2C145`

At the end after `/DSC09923.jpg` you have `?resize=116%2C145` which mean `resizing in 116px x 145px`, because this small defined images are displayed in a zoomed version, I mean like 250% larger. so they get blurred. See the html generated code:

```
<img width="116" height="145" src="http://i0.wp.com/yarnhk.com//wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DSC09923.jpg?resize=350%2C435" 
class="lazyOwl wp-post-image" 
alt="AERO Needles" 
data-src="http://i0.wp.com/yarnhk.com//wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DSC09923.jpg?resize=350%2C435" 
srcset="http://i0.wp.com/yarnhk.com//wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DSC09923.jpg?resize=350%2C435 350w, 
http://i0.wp.com/yarnhk.com//wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DSC09923.jpg?resize=570%2C708 570w, 
http://i0.wp.com/yarnhk.com//wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DSC09923.jpg?resize=116%2C145 116w, 
http://i0.wp.com/yarnhk.com//wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DSC09923.jpg?resize=190%2C236 190w" 
sizes="(max-width: 116px) 100vw, 116px" style="opacity: 1;">
```

I don't know how you display that 4 images in the home page, so it's difficult for me to find out the real problem. You will need to specify sizes for that images: 'medium' or 'large'…

You may need in wooCommerce > settings > Products > Display to re-configure sizes and hard-cropping options…

Comment: I also saw the captured html code, but I do not know what to do next. In Commerce > settings > Products > Display,  I have resized the images into: catelog 350x435pixels; single 570 x 708 pixcels; thumbnails 350 x 435 pixels. I used "Visual Composer" to do my homepage.  Hope i can get more advice on this.

Comment: I am using Visual Composer, in which I use "Multiple/ Specific Products" to showcase the 4 products (by using their ID).

Comment: Then you have to change settings in visual composer. You may be ask in support threads of your premium theme or in VC support too if you got a license… That's the best options.

Comment: I can share the code I found it from Visual Composer: [/vc_column_text][products ids="6975,6980,6977,86,11583,11587,88,11808,11807"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row columns_height="adjust_cols_height" background_style="normal" css=".vc_custom_1445415612639{margin-bottom: 50px !important;}"]

Comment: I have tried many ways, including re-load the product photos, add a new product item with the same product photos with a new name etc, and now  it seems the photos return to normal: www.doubleknityarn.com.hk.  You can take a look, but I do not know if it is only temporary or not.

Comment: I further found out that there is a difference between Chrome and IE. http://doubleknityarn.com.hk/product-category/%e6%ad%90%e6%b4%b2%e6%af%9b%e5%86%b7/ You will see the difference on the product thumbnails between the 2 browsers - products in IE are all clear, while some products in Chrome are blurry.

Any ideas on what happens?

Comment: Have you try to contact the theme author support?